# Samsung Galaxy Tab E - "An error has occurred while updating the device software."

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, odin, samsung-smart-switch, download-mode

When I try to boot my Samsung Galaxy Tab E 9.6, it comes up with this error:
"An error has occurred while updating the device software. Use the Emergency Recovery function in the SmartSwitch PC Software."

[image]

I tried using SmartSwitch but it always repeats Plugin as Administrator and doesn't really do anything.
It connects to Odin but cannot flash.